# Django .objects,get for merged querysets from different models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filters

I have an abstract base model ('Base') from which two models inherit: 'Movie' and 'Cartoon'. I display a list of both movies and cartoons to the user (with the help of itertools.chain). Then I want to give the user the opportunity to delete any of these items, without knowing in advance whether it is a movie or a cartoon. I am trying to do it like this:

```
        ...

        movies = Movie.objects.filter(user_created=userlist).order_by('title')
        cartoons = Cartoon.objects.filter(user_created=userlist).order_by('title')

        all_items = list(chain(movies, cartoons))

        item = all_items.get(id=item_id)
        item.delete()
```

But then PyCharm states,

> Unresolved attribute reference 'get' for class 'list'

I understand why this happens but I don't know how to avoid it. Is there any way to merge two querysets from different models and apply get or filter without removing the abstract base model and creating a physical parent model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ContentTypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) for a generic and reusable solution to this for an arbitrary number of different models. But I also wonder why `Cartoon` and `Movie` must be different types to begin with; it may be worth spending a little time thinking about whether you can use a single model for both types of media - deletion of an arbitrary instance is just one of many cases where a single model will be more straightforward than relying on something like ContentTypes.

EDIT: For more info on ContentTypes. You could either create a base model with a generic relation (you said you didn't want to do this), or for the deletion you could include app label and model name in the request data alongside item id, enabling lookups like:

```py
    media_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model_name)
    instance = media_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=item_id)
    instance.delete()
```

what's nice about this approach is you'd barely have to change your model structure.

Comment: I am interested specifically in working with multiple models. For example, a Cartoon object can have fields such as 'paint_used' or 'for_adults', etc., while a Movie object can have fields such as 'movie_type', 'age_restriction', and so on. I don't like using all fields for both models filling these object-specific fields with None, as this would mess everything up. I have seen the ContentTypes framework documentation but yet have no idea of how it can be applied here. I will try to find some more information.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info about ContentType lookups

Comment: Thanks. it's a good answer. My last question: would it be more efficient to use a separate physical model instead of ContentTypes? Consider that I will have 60 different types of objects (Movie, Cartoon, Concert, Novel, etc.). Having a separate physical model would mean using many joins. On the other hand, it already seems more intuitive and friendly to me at this point (in contrast to what I had thought initially).

Comment: The standard advice is generally not to worry about performance until you have to, and if you don't have a working product or any users yet, then you don't have to. WIthout more detailed understanding this is the only advice I think I can offer. 60 is not really *that many* types; with judicious indexing, caching, etc I wouldn't imagine performance to be a huge issue, but only you are in a position to know what's best in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

you can first find the index using index() method and then can get item by all_items[given_index].delete()